# CoreData - how to create fetchrequest to get array of random attribute values

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-data

I have simple model with 2 entities **House** and **Flat**. **House** has to many relation to **Flat**. **Flat** has attributes like **number** and **description**.

I would like to get a list of random eight flat numbers.

I'm trying to go this way, but it seems that' wrong

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"House" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    NSArray *houses = [aFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

Then I need to get appropriate values.

Please show me a right approach.

I try to answer myself. Perhaps my brains are dry:)
Just need

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Flat" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

and then work with array of fetched objects. But I'm steel believe that there is more elegant solution.

I have further question related to the first one. 
How to get random objects if number of flats is about 10000? In general it works but slows down noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

LimitSort the records randomly and set `[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:8];` to get the first eight. For random sorting make a `NSSortDescriptor` with selector or comparator that returns `NSComparisonResult` randomly and add this descriptor to the fetch request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But did you mean [fetchRequest setFetchLimits:8]

Comment: Oops! Yes, I meant `setFetchLimit:`